# VLC media player-back 10 seconds and forward 30 seconds buttons are missing

Tags: vlc-media-player

In VLC media player, I used to have a "jump back 10 seconds" button at the middle of the bottom of the screen while playing a video, and a "jump forward 30 seconds" button. These buttons have disappeared and I cannot find any information anywhere on how to retrieve them.

I have found the "hotkeys", but they are not nearly as convenient as these other buttons used to be, making my job take a lot longer than it used to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Super helpful!!  Thank you, It doesn't look exactly the same as it did before, but this has completely solved my problem -- THANK YOU!!

Comment: If your question has been successfully answered, please mark it as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

*(Note, this is on Windows, I'm not sure if this applies to all OSs)*

Go to 'Tools' - 'Customize Interface' to bring up the window for editing the player.

Under 'Toolbar Elements' scroll down and find the 'Step backward' then drag and drop that onto the part of the interface you want on 'Line 2'. Then do the same for 'Step forward' as well. Then click the 'close' button.

That will add the 'step backwards' and 'step forwards' buttons to the VLC player.

I'm not sure about how to just change the timing for forward to 30secs. From looking at the settings the backward/forward uses the same variable when changed. Maybe someone else will point out how to just change the forward from 10 secs to 30 secs.